# JAX-WS: define server side handler chain in code and not in external xml

Tags: http, soap, jax-ws, handler, chain

i want to enable http compression for my jax-ws webservice. i found out that i have to do it with a custom handlerchain that can modify the http-headers.

all tutorials i found refer to the annotation @HandlerChain that points to a handler chain configuration xml-file but my problem is that my webservice has to be as lightweight as possible therefore i cant define my handler chain in an external xml file.

i tried the following but did not succeed:

```
        final Endpoint ep = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8878/mywebservice",
                new WebserviceImpl() );
        final Binding binding = ep.getBinding();
        final List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
        handlerChain.add(new MySuperbSOAPHandler());
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

does anyone know how to do this? is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can change the handler chain when the service has already been published.

If your actual use case is as above, it's easy to fix by simply create()ing and then publish()ing.

```
    final Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new WebserviceImpl() );
    final Binding binding = ep.getBinding();
    final List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
    handlerChain.add(new MySuperbSOAPHandler());
    binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
    ep.publish("http://localhost:8878/mywebservice");
```

Comment: even more confusing is the fact that -- if you add the handler after publishing -- the `getBinding().getHandlerChain()` List *does* contain the new Handler, yet it is not being used.